# what does のも mean at the end of a clause?

Tags: particles

I've run into this use of も a few times and I'm not sure what to make of it. Here's the sentence I'm confused about:

> 余裕を見せていられる**のも**、いまの内だ。

Comment: Where did you find this? Just curious :).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 「[余裕]{よゆう}を[見]{み}せていられる**のも**、いまの[内]{うち}だ。」

The 「の」 is a nominalizing particle.  It enables the verb phrase 「見せていられる」 to function as a noun.

The 「も」 is kind of like "also" but not quite in that it only hints at a possibility that there might be another thing that the speaker thinks applies besides 余裕を見せていられること.

> 「"Verb phrase in potential" + の + も + いまのうちだ。」 means:
>
> "The situation where you could be (verb phrase) will not last long."

余裕を見せていられる = "(you could be) looking like you have leeway"